# Создание приложения интернет-магазина Вконтакте на основе готового сайта

Tags: rest, flash, javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте.

Требуется сделать приложение Вконтакте, которое, по сути, будет интернет-магазином на основе уже готового интернет-магазина.

Собственно, есть стандартный серверный набор: php, mysql,apache + opencart CMS. 
Магазин хорошо работает. Нужно теперь сделать приложение ВКонтакте, которое будет предоставлять пользователям ВКонтакте стандартный набор функций интернет-магазина. То есть пользователь установил приложение, подтвердил доступ к своим данным и автоматически зарегистрировался в базе. При следующем запуске приложения пользователь уже без всяких запросов, автоматически попадает приложение уже залогиненым. ТО есть обычная практика приложений ВКонтакте.

Вопрос вот в чем. Я до этого особо не имел дела с такими вещами. Вот хочу попросить совета у более опытных людей в данном деле, дабы следовать стандартным общепринятым шаблонам создания таких приложений, а также не создавать своих велосипедов.

Насколько я понял, есть два основных способа создания приложения ВКонтакте:

1. IFrame. Тут все понятно JS, PHP....
2. Flash.

Собственно вопрос: какой способ лучше для данных нужд. Либо делать это через IFrame, использую, к примеру, одностраничное приложение, написанное на JS и других библиотеках, написанных на нем. То есть приложение будет предоставлять собой одну страницу, которая с помощью AJAX будет делать, к примеру, REST запросы на сервер.
Или же лучше делать приложение через Flash.

RESTful API будет в любом случае, так как требуется еще доступ с мобильного клиента. 
Собственно, хотелось бы услышать мнения и советы знающих в этой сфере людей, как лучше сделать, что использовать, может, есть какое-то эталонное приложение для реализации таких целей.

Спасибо всем заранее. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash - умирает, и делать на нем что-либо не перспективно.

Раз у Вас есть готовый сайт, используйте iframe, просто прикрутите шаблон, адаптированный под размеры фрэйма и все.

Зачем писать отдельное одностраничное приложение на js? У Вас в распоряжении готовая cms, нужно лишь найти\написать плагин, который будет обрабатывать запросы через фрэйм и все.

> Поясню, если у Вас сайт живет не только в рамках приложения для вк (что скорее всего), будет логично сделать отдельную точку входа для пользователей из приложения, на которой будет проверяться, есть ли пользователь, который зашел на сайт в базе, если такого пользователя нет, будет его мгновенно регистрировать и отправлять на нужную страницу на сайте (приложении), возможно, попутно цепляя параметр к url, который будет говорить, что сайт запущен через приложение, и нужно отобразить шаблон приложения.

Т.е. делать в данном случае SPA нецелесообразно.

P.S. Насколько я знаю, когда пользователь открывает сайт через приложение вк, первая страница сайта открывается с параметрами, которые позволяют идентифицировать пользователя через соц. сеть (id пользователя, токен), что и позволит проверять наличие данного пользователя в общей базе пользователей магазина.